# SearchView to Edittext search

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm android beginner  i have code that search MySQL database using json and display results my problen now i want to change SearchView to EditText(id) and Button (searchbtn) when clicks  the searchbutton it gives me results how can i change this to do it

```
 mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            final Call<List<Spacecraft>> call = myAPIService.searchSpacecraft(query);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Spacecraft>>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Response<List<Spacecraft>> response) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    populateListView(response.body());
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    populateListView(new ArrayList<Spacecraft>());
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR: "+throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the issue with onQueryTextChanged or onQueryTextSubmit ?

Comment: Just get the text from your editText by  yourEditText.getText();  and pass the value to your request .. all this in the onButtonClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the text from your editText by yourEditText.getText(); and pass the value to your request .. all this in the onButtonClickListener

follow belwo code

```
 searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Get the value from edit text
                          String result = yourEdittext.getText().toString();
                        //Then pass the value to your request like that 
           final Call<List<Spacecraft>> call = myAPIService.searchSpacecraft(result);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Spacecraft>>() {
    
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Response<List<Spacecraft>> response) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        populateListView(response.body());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Throwable throwable) {
                        populateListView(new ArrayList<Spacecraft>());
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR: "+throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        
                    }
                });
```

Comment: great , only small problem     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: where did you initialize your edittext ? it must be in public scope to to use it in any where

Comment: can i do search without using button i mean like  onCreate view

Comment: Yes you can using filter in RecyclerView and using SearchView